Chain rule with a variable held constant (or along a constant surface)
Say we have a Cartesian function, $f(x,y)$ and we move to a polar coordinate scheme
$g(r,\theta)$,
$$g(r,\theta) = f(x,y) \\ \therefore x = x(r,\theta), y = y(r,\theta)$$
Just to lay out the definitions, the definition for a partial derivative wrt to the new coordinate is:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u_i} = \sum_j \frac{\partial \bar{u}_j}{\partial u_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{u_j}}$$
And the definition of a partial derivative wrt to the original transformed coordinate is:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{u_i}} = \sum_j \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial \bar{u_i}}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_j}$$
where the $\bar{}$ denotes a transformed variable. For example, x would be a transformed variable as it was transformed into a function of $r$ and $\theta$. Using these formulae to take say $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial r}$ or $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ (taking into account that x is a transformed coordinate in this context) is simple enough, but say we want to take:
$$\tag{1}\Big(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\Big)_y$$ which means that we perform the derivative with y held constant (or we could say along a surface of constant y), or another example:
$$\tag{2}\Big(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial r}\Big)_x$$,
where x would would be held constant; what would be the generalized formulae for the partial derivatives under these circumstances.

NOTE: From some examples I've seen in an old textbook (none of which were worked out), unless the formulae for the partial derivatives changed, it seemed to me like the functions themselves changed in some way depending on what was being explicitly held constant, though I don't know exactly how. This is what I would like to figure out.
I would think it would be as simple as $\Big(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial r}\Big)_x = \frac{\partial f(c,y)}{\partial r}$, and we would just say the derivatives involving c would be 0 and the RHS would simply evaluate to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$, but it and I would like to understand why.

You wrote in a comment here that it was made clear to you. Was it not? From (2) onwards your notation above becomes again the nonsense that I thought we eliminated together. Instead, just partially differentate $g.$

@KurtG. Actually I found a resource that explained exactly what it was that I was misunderstanding. Yes I understand how the chain rule works from that example and in the cases of transformed coordinates. What I did not understand was how it worked from the standpoint that a variable was explicitly being held constant. What I should have done. The question was about how the process changed under those circumstances, however, from what I found it doesn't change at all actually.

This was the resource which helped me figure it out. To help illustrate we should start by writing out the differential and then performing a partial derivative with a variable held constant. So $$dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  r}dr + \frac{\partial  g}{\partial  x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}d\theta $$ ran out of space for y

Good that you found a resource that confirms what we both already knew. Imho better than trying to find resources is it to view the chain rule as a fundamental principle that answers a lot of questions by itself. Edit. That $g$ depends now on $x$ and $y$ while previously it was $f.$ That is why I do not recommend gratuitous resources.

and then say if we took $$\Big(\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}\Big)_r$$, the result would be (for just the x term to save room): $$dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial  r} \Big(\frac{\partial r}{\partial r}\Big)_r + \frac{\partial  g}{\partial  x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\Big(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial r}\Big)_r$$ $$=  0 + \frac{\partial  g}{\partial  x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\Big(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial r}\Big)_r$$ because the term $\Big(\frac{\partial r}{\partial r}\Big)_r$ with r held as a constant = 0

They say nonsense because of the mess with the notation. $r$ or $x$ ? make up your mind guys!

the example is just $dg$ where I cut off the differentiation for the y term because I ran out of characters. There would have been four terms being differentiated if I had the space. I should probably just type out the full answer rather than make things more confusing in the comments. sorry about that!

sorry not $dg$, I meant $$\Big(\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}\Big)_r = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}\Big(\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial r}\Big)$$. Just a note for you and any future reader

Please read my answer, put the resources aside and write out formula (3). What nonsense is $\Big(\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}\Big)_r,?$ A partial derivative of $g$ where $\color{red}r$ is held constant?  You make me curious to know who writes such crap. Just looking at the link: a chemist.

Oh and that was something I entirely made up as I hastily made an example to prove a point. That was not something pulled from the resource, they never make that mistake. I fully understand that that was not a legal operation. The point was to show that If we came across $\Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Big)|{u = c}$, then the result would be 0.

In that case the chemist is exempt from my further punishment. :) Let's close this session and let things settle down. Cu next time.

It's 1 am where I am and I didn't eat dinner (which is pretty common for me bc I'm kind of a mess), so suffice to say my mental state isn't always at its peak and I can make very careless mistakes. I can see that my carelessness in typing some of these things out and perhaps my phrasing has led to quite a bit of confusion and frustration. I apologize for that! Thank you for your patience! I'll go ahead and close this.

Too long for a comment. That sloppy formula
$$
\tag{2}\Big(\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial r}\Big)_x
$$
indicates that you want to take the total differential of
$$
f\big(c,y(r,\theta)\big)
$$
w.r.t. $r$
and after that replace $c$ by $x\,.$ A clearer notation for that is
$$\tag{3}
\frac{d}{dr}f\big(c,y(r,\theta)\big)\Bigg|_{c=x}\,.
$$
Now please apply the chain rule and write that out. The comments indicate that
you know how to do that.

One more comment which will hopefully not be too confusing: in (3) it does not really matter if we write $\frac{d}{dr}$ or $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\,.$ What matters is that we know what is held constant and on what variables the functions depend on.

Before I have to write further comments. Here is my preferred solution of writing out (3)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)\,.$$ Strictly speaking this should be a function of $x$ and $(r,\theta)$ and we may want to disentangle the $\partial _y$ notation a bit: $$\partial_2f\big(x,y(r\,\theta)\big)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)\,.$$Another possibility to do that is$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\Bigg|_{y=y(r,\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)\,.$$


$$\frac{d}{dr} f(c,y(r,\theta))|_{c=x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dr}$$

Very sloppy to the point of being wrong. Where did the $c$ go? Where is the $x$ that we wanted to be constant? $\frac{dy}{dr},?$ this is the worst. $y$ depends on two variables.

but we're differentiating wrt to r aren't we? Is x not a constant? I excluded it from the chain rule because I thought it would be a constant

For (3) if we're performing total differentiation (hence the d instead of $\partial$) I should get with the more accurate notation (of which you provided examples): $$\frac{\partial }{\partial r} f(c,y(r,\theta))|{c=x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}f(c,y)|{c=x}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}y(r,\theta)$$. I would have used $\frac{d}{dr}$ because (3) used the total differentiation symbol, however, you said to disregard this.

Saying it "does not matter" is hugely different from disregarding it, and I wrote that any notation that makes clear what is held constant will do.

Yeah that's how I interpreted what you were saying. "disregard" as is disregard whether one or the other is used. I understood the takeaway. As in I shouldn't pay special attention to one or the other. That's how I meant it when I used that word.
